# can AVAudioPlayer trigger events on predefined intervals?

Tags: swift, ipad, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I need to make views visible at fixed time while running a MP3 audio. I am using Swift. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like using timers if drawing depends on them. They may fire more frequently than the screen redraws or out of sync with the screen drawing. I use a CADisplayLink instead. It's similar to a timer but it is designed to fire in synch with the screen's refresh rate. You could implement something like this.

```
var messagePlaybackTimer: CADisplayLink?
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func playAudioData(){
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audio", ofType: "mp3")
    var url: NSURL

    if let audioResourcePath = path {
        url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(audioResourcePath)!
    }else{
        return;
    }

    player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)

    messagePlaybackTimer?.invalidate()
    messagePlaybackTimer = nil;

    messagePlaybackTimer = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: Selector("messagePlaybackTimerFired"))

    messagePlaybackTimer?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

    player?.play()
}

func messagePlaybackTimerFired(){
    println(player?.currentTime)
}
```

In messagePlaybackTimerFired() you can check the AVAudioPlayer's current time and fire events based on that. (E.g. if player?.currentTime > 5 && player?.currentTime < 6 { do something } )

This will allow you to fire the method at as close to 5 seconds as possible while still being optimal for doing UI work.

When you are done with the CADisplayLink (when the player stops playing) be sure to invalidate it. If you don't, it will keep firing when you don't need it anymore.

Another thing you can do is fire off an NSNotification in messagePlaybackTimerFired() and your UIViewController can subscribe to the notification and show the views when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `NSTimer` or the AVAudioPlayer's `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` method to check the value, it's (very most likely) not possible to get updates when a certain time is reached.

Oh and for a Swiftier NSTimer I suggest [this](http://radex.io/swift/nstimer/)